# Android -gradle task -Azure devops - Pipeline No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

Tags: android, azure-devops, android-ndk

I am trying to configure a CI pipeline in azure DevOps on Microsoft Hosted agent (windows-latest)
gradle - 6.9
gradle plugin version :- 3.5.3
Getting below mentioned error :-

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':ucrop:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Can anyone guide me on this how to give path for ndk through pipeline YAML or any best possible solution because i can't update gradle plugin version.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. While debugging I found $ANDROID_HOME_NDK is now version 21.4.7075529 in DevOps hosted agent agents

`Warning: Observed package id 'ndk;21.4.7075529' in inconsistent location '/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle' (Expected '/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529')`

But for some reason the pipeline is using NDK version 23, that's causing the error.

Setting the ndkVersion property in app build.gradle fixed the CI build.

```
android {
    ...
    ndkVersion "21.4.7075529"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this command and it worked for me

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "XA5101/NDK r22 Workaround"
  inputs:
    script: |
      ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;21.4.7075529"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ANDROID_NDK_HOME;]$ANDROID_HOME/ndk/21.4.7075529"
      echo 'Done!'
```